# New to PowerShell and sof, loopsI b

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a loop that shows top ten process by cpu usage and want it to refresh every 10 seconds, but I only want it to run 3 times then stop. So I make

```
$psloop = ps | sort -desc cpu | select -f 10
```

then I run,

```
for ($counter=0; $counter -lt 10; $counter++) {
     start-sleep -s 10; 
     $psloop; 
     echo "top procs for 10 seconds--"
}
```

but it just keeps running how do I make it stop, thanks for any help.

Comment: See [`Get-Counter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.2), should be more appropriate for this.

Comment: Change the `-lt 10` to `-lt 3`.

Comment: You'll also need to run ```$psloop = ps | sort -desc cpu | select -f 10 ``` *inside* your loop, otherwise all you're doing is capturing a list of the top 10 processes that were active at the start of your program into a variable and showing that same list each time the loop runs.